# Class not found when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState

Tags: java, android, xml, api, maps

i am using Maps API  to create a simple android app and i get a wierd error i can't solve. It usually happens when i rotate my device. I'm using google services 8.4.0

```
4-23 15:39:47.503 9419-9419/com.licenta.vladut.mmap E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState
                                                               java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState
                                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2275)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2239)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2146)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2540)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1868)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2203)
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2479)
                                                                   at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                                                   at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:782)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ao.a(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:74)
                                                                   at maps.ei.bu.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at maps.ei.n.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i$a.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:107)
                                                                   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2315)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
                                                                   at com.licenta.vladut.mmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:149)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1290)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000000/DynamiteModules-prod.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000000/n/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.f
04-23 15:39:47.503 9419-9419/com.licenta.vladut.mmap D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-23 15:39:47.505 9419-9419/com.licenta.vladut.mmap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.licenta.vladut.mmap, PID: 9419
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.licenta.vladut.mmap/com.licenta.vladut.mmap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:149)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1290)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
                                                                           at com.licenta.vladut.mmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:149) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1290) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
                                                                        Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2289)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2239)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2146)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2540)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1868)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2203)
                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2479)
                                                                           at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                                                           at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:782)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ao.a(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:74)
                                                                           at maps.ei.bu.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at maps.ei.n.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i$a.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:107)
                                                                           at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2315)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInf
```

My MainActivity.java  is

```
package com.licenta.vladut.mmap;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap mMap;
    private static  final double BM_LAT = 47.6595076, BM_LNG = 23.5631243;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9002;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            (MainActivity.this).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.sign_out) {
            signOut();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        toSignIn();
                    }


                });
    }

    private void toSignIn() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.onConnectionFailed) + connectionResult);
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
                googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                        ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Nu se poate conecta la Google Play Services!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {
        this.mMap = map;
        gotoLocation(BM_LAT,BM_LNG,18);
    }
    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom){
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.licenta.vladut.mmap.MainActivity">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_map.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        />
    </fragment>
```

and finally, toolbar.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I would guess that it's because you have the `Toolbar` nested within the Map `Fragment`, which is unusual. Try pulling the `<include>` out of the `<fragment>`, and put them both in another `ViewGroup`; e.g., a vertical `LinearLayout`, or a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you. Putting both in a RelativeLayout works like a charm. You should post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: what is the android version? This only happened in the api 10. Because I've ever had this error and still I don't fixed.

Comment: I was using api 23, Mike's solution worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upon rotation, your `SupportMapFragment` gets destroyed and recreated. Before it's destroyed, it writes its current state to a `Parcel`, to be used in restoring its state when recreated. The `Fragment`'s saved state will include the state of its child `View`s, and since you've nested a `Toolbar` within it, it attempts to save and restore that, as well. The `Toolbar` class does not have an inner class `SavedState` necessary for that, so this process fails when trying to restore the `Toolbar` instance from the `Parcel`.

The solution is to not nest the `Toolbar` - or any other `View`, for that matter - within the `<fragment>` element. Instead, pull the `<include>` out of the `<fragment>`, and put them both in another `ViewGroup`; for example, a vertical `LinearLayout`, or a `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 11):

I didn't like provided solutions as it imposed on my layouts and architecture.

Here's what I did to make it work. If you look at your stacktrace the ClassNotFoundException is coming from the line on GoogleMaps. So if we just fix that, the issue is gone.

GoogleMaps pukes/throw an error when the savedInstanceState has other items in it besides it's own. The solution is to just give GoogleMaps it's own dedicated bundle.

```
// class property
private static final String KEY_MAP_SAVED_STATE = "mapState";

// class methods
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mapView = findMapView();  // make your own method here
    Bundle mapState = (savedInstanceState != null)
            ? savedInstanceState.getBundle(KEY_MAP_SAVED_STATE): null;
    mapView.onCreate(mapState);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Bundle mapState = new Bundle();
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapState);
    outState.putBundle(KEY_MAP_SAVED_STATE, mapState);
}
```

One thing to note is I'm not using the SupportMapFragment. I'm using a MapView directly. You may have to extend the SupportMapFragment so you can catch the hook methods and provide a blank/clean bundle

Comment: Agreed. I have the same problem, but in this case the the failure is `Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState`. My RecyclerView is already coming in on an `<include>`, so the marked answer would not solve my issue, but this does.

Comment: This worked perfectly for salving my issue with an error of ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState.  +2 for not requiring me to change my layouts.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with my custom view and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40241161/2212770) solution.
I noticed that this crash occurred when I extended **RecyclerView** or **AppCompatSpinner** and needed to save the state. The crash will probably happen for other views as well.

Basically the crash is caused by a bug in AbsSavedState as mentioned [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37073849#comment36).
And the crash only occurs when the constructor of the SavedState is called without a class loader. It seemed like this was an old issue however I started getting crash reports for Android 9 and 10.

So the fix was to change:

```
public SavedState(Parcel source) {
  super(source);
  //... 
}
```

to:

```
public SavedState(Parcel source) {
  super(source, LinearLayoutManager.class.getClassLoader());
  //... 
}
```

**Edit**
I was on the right track, but then I was looking at some [Android code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/viewpager2/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.java#412) and found out that there was actually a constructor missing that caused the crash. So I had the following constructor for the SavedState:

```
SavedState(Parcel in)
{
    super(in);
    //...
}
```

And I needed to add the following:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
SavedState(Parcel in, ClassLoader loader)
{
    super(in, loader);
    //...
}
```

And then I needed to change the creator:

```
public static final Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new ClassLoaderCreator<SavedState>()
{
    @Override
    public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel source, ClassLoader loader)
    {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N ? new SavedState(source, loader) : new SavedState(source);
    }

    @Override
    public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel source)
    {
        return createFromParcel(source, null);
    }

    public SavedState[] newArray(int size)
    {
        return new SavedState[size];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing activity_map.xml to this  worked, thanks again Mike.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </fragment>
</RelativeLayout>
```