# Exception during screen rotation: Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, admob

This exception appears when screen rotate, during the call to: onCreate() and its super method: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

It seems to be related or the same as this thread : [Why is there ClassNotFoundException when i change screen orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55597662/10925023)
but unfortunatly, the proposed solutions does not work. Removing the AdView does not change anything.

Here is the full stack:

```
E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2827)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2781)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2684)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3053)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:288)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:232)
        at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:917)
        at gh.onActivityCreated(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@17122081@17.1.22 (100400-245988633):32)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.onActivityCreated(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@17122081@17.1.22 (100400-245988633):88)
        at cp.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@17122081@17.1.22 (100400-245988633):169)
        at j.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@17122081@17.1.22 (100400-245988633):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:675)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzq.zza(Unknown Source:20)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdp.onActivityCreated(Unknown Source:144)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzex.zzgd(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzea$zzb.run(Unknown Source:11)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:1346)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:1406)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2827) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2781) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2684) 
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3053) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:288) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:232) 
        at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:917) 
        at gh.onActivityCreated(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@17122081@17.1.22 (100400-245988633):32) 
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.onActivityCreated(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@17122081@17.1.22 (100400-245988633):88) 
        at cp.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@17122081@17.1.22 (100400-245988633):169) 
        at j.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@17122081@17.1.22 (100400-245988633):4) 
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:675) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzq.zza(Unknown Source:20) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdp.onActivityCreated(Unknown Source:144) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzex.zzgd(Unknown Source:4) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzea$zzb.run(Unknown Source:11) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

there's an additional warning for W/FA-ADS

```
W/FA-Ads: Error with data collection. Data lost.
    android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2917)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2843)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2746)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3115)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:273)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:226)
        at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:916)
        at kh.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@19275051@19.2.75 (040408-269183835):35)
        at jz.onActivityCreated(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@19275051@19.2.75 (040408-269183835):22)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.onActivityCreated(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@19275051@19.2.75 (040408-269183835):129)
        at cq.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@19275051@19.2.75 (040408-269183835):160)
        at j.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@19275051@19.2.75 (040408-269183835):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:627)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzb.zza(Unknown Source:20)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzm.onActivityCreated(Unknown Source:144)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbd.zzf(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzz$zzb.run(Unknown Source:11)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: maybe it's a bug on `Oppo` device. Here's the related issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135627416

Comment: I've got a Samsung Galaxy S10. Do you think the ROM is bugged too ?

Comment: @Cyrille Do you already know where the exception comes from, and/or how to prevent it? I get exact same exception on configuration change and activity recreate. It doesn't seem to break anything, but I would rather prevent it from happening.

Comment: I still don't know, i wil try with another device during christmas.

Answer (score 2):

Your source code is obfuscated using proguard .

Are your sure "androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState" class is excluded from proguard.

if not please add  & try it

```
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable { 
   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *; 
}
```

Comment: Sadly it does not work. It happen in debug mode without proguard too.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 
`implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0'`
into `build.gradle`. It helped me.

By providing the implementation of `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState` this problem disappears.

*Note that version(1.2.0) you want to use may differ(newer/older)*

Comment: I just try with 1.2.1 version, but I have the exact same error

Comment: I just have found that there is another exception before this one. This one is generated when the fragment state is going to be restored. I was using android studio with opened logcat with enabled filtering of logs from my application (Show only selected application). When I disabled that filter i have discovered another exception.

Comment: Which exception ? I saw nothing on my side.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exception and it took me a while to figure out what happened.  I believe my situation is exactly the same as what @Amirr0r mentioned in his comment, so it may be worthwhile to report it here.
The key is displaying everything in Logcat window with "**No Filters**". There should be a crashing exception or ANR before this odd exception.  In my case, it is an ANR caused by a foreground service. Once that ANR was taken care of, this problem is gone.